# Change Width of Header Widget in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, header, widget, width

**I created a header widget. I used this code:**

**First, I placed this code into Functions.php**

```
    function wpb_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Header Widget',
    'id' => 'header-widget',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="hw-widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="hw-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
```

**Then I added this code into header.php**

```
<?php

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'header-widget' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="header-widget-area" class="hw-widget widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'header-widget' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Now my width of the widget seems to be smaller than my container width. I'd like to change that.
I tried using this code:**

```
.header-widget {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

But it does not seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your widget has the class .header-widget  ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no class named `header-widget` in front end. `header-widget` is an ID of widget in backend. If you want to write CSS for your widget in front end then you can use `header-widget-area` or `hw-widget widget-area` as below. I tried and it worked for  me in localhost.

```
#header-widget-area {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

or

```
.header-widget {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```